# Spring JUnit - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to write a unit test case for my Spring MVC application. I am using pure Java Config, no XML.

When I try to run my test class I get the following stack trace. (This is only part of the stack trace. The full trace is too big to post on stack overflow.)

```
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userMapper' defined in file [/Users/jkratz/Projects/knowledge-works/build/classes/main/org/ohiohighered/researchportal/core/persistence/UserMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/ohiohighered/researchportal/core/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in class path resource [org/ohiohighered/researchportal/core/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [jndi.datasource] not found; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/ohiohighered/researchportal/core/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in class path resource [org/ohiohighered/researchportal/core/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [jndi.datasource] not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [aysnc.executor.poolSize] not found
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.getRequiredProperty(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:160)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getRequiredProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:541)
    at org.ohiohighered.researchportal.core.config.JobConfig.getAsyncExecutor(JobConfig.java:26)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AbstractAsyncConfiguration.setConfigurers(AbstractAsyncConfiguration.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 53 more
```

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class CampusParserTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void testParser() {

        CampusParser campusParser = new CampusParser();
        campusParser.parse();
    }
}
```

For some reason it does not seem to be instantiating any of my beans or finding any property / config files. This is a Spring MVC application that I'm running on Tomcat 8. The datasource is also loading from JNDI which I'm guessing will be an issue but one thing at a time.

UPDATE: Here is my PersistenceConfig. The application loads and runs fine with Tomcat 8.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@MapperScan("org.app.researchportal.core.persistence")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    /**
     * Gets the datasource from the container using JNDI and returns it
     *
     * @return {@link DataSource}
     */
    @Bean(name = "datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        return dsLookup.getDataSource(environment.getRequiredProperty("jndi.datasource"));
    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns the MyBatis SqlSessionFactoryBean
     *
     * @return SqlSessionFactoryBean
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("org.app.researchportal.core.domain");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * creates the AtomikosTransactionManager bean for JTA transactions
     *
     * @return UserTransactionManager
     */
    @Bean(name="AtomikosTransactionManager", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager() {
        UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
        return userTransactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * create the UserTransaction bean for Atomikos JTA implementation
     *
     * @return UserTransactionImp
     * @throws SystemException
     */
    @Bean(name = "AtomikosUserTransaction")
    public UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp() throws SystemException{
        UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
        userTransactionImp.setTransactionTimeout(300);
        return userTransactionImp;
    }

    /**
     * create the JtaTransactionManger bean to manage transactions
     *
     * @return JtaTransactionManager
     * @throws SystemException
     */
    @Bean(name = "JtaTransactionManager")
    public JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager() throws SystemException {
        JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        jtaTransactionManager.setTransactionManager(userTransactionManager());
        jtaTransactionManager.setUserTransaction(userTransactionImp());
        return jtaTransactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * creates Flyway bean to automatically handle database migrations
     *
     * @return Flyway
     */
    @Bean(name = "flyway", initMethod = "migrate")
    public Flyway flyway() {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setDataSource(dataSource());
        flyway.setOutOfOrder(false);
        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
        flyway.setLocations("classpath:migrations");
        return flyway;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a circular dependency somewhere? It looks like the bean `dataSource` wants to have `sqlSessionFactory` injected, which wants to have `dataSource` injected, which wants to have `sqlSessionFactory` injected, which wants to ... etc.

Comment: I updated the question. It works fine within Tomcat. For whatever reason it appears not loading the property files seems to be the root cause

Comment: The property file which is getting loaded doesnot have the "aysnc.executor.poolSize" and this is the primary exception which is leading to others. So add @propertySource("filename") to load the property file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must forget to configure "datasource" like:

```
 <property name="driverClassName" value=
 <property name="url" value=
```